# Javascript convert date to roman date

Tags: javascript

I have the following code that converts a date input into a roman date:

```
function romanize (num) {
  if (!+num)
    return false;
  var digits = String(+num).split(""),
    key = ["","C","CC","CCC","CD","D","DC","DCC","DCCC","CM",
           "","X","XX","XXX","XL","L","LX","LXX","LXXX","XC",
           "","I","II","III","IV","V","VI","VII","VIII","IX"],
    roman = "",
    i = 3;
  while (i--)
    roman = (key[+digits.pop() + (i * 10)] || "") + roman;
  return Array(+digits.join("") + 1).join("M") + roman;
}

$(document).on("change",'#date', function() {
    var date = new Date($('#date').val());
    day = date.getDate();
    month = date.getMonth() + 1;
    year = date.getFullYear();
    var strRomanDate = romanize(month) + " " + romanize(day) + " " + romanize(year); 
    $('#romandate .date').html(strRomanDate);
});
```

Now, this is working fine for some dates, for ex:

```
10/04/2018 --> X IV MMXVIII
```

But when I want to select a day after 12, so 13, 14,... It returns `false false false`.

Anyone have an idea what I should change in my code to make it work for every date?

Comment: I am not able to replicate your issue. Please create a working snippet that demonstrate your issue.

Comment: Seems to work for me: https://jsfiddle.net/xpvt214o/89320/

Comment: Try entering `13/03/2008`

Comment: @DanielBeck In your fiddle, when I enter 13/03/2018 is returns false false false. I think one way or another it switches the day and month

Comment: @SenneVandenputte yeah that's because 13 isn't a valid month

Comment: The date input is probably in `MM/DD/YYYY`, which format are you expecting?

Comment: The date input should be in DD/MM/YYYY. I think there's the problem. When I change the input to MM/DD/YYYY it works correctly. But I need it to be formatted as DD/MM/YYYY for the users

Comment: In javascript, by default, if the date is not in ISO format, it will be parsed as MM/DD/YYYY. I'd recommend using a different Date library like Datejs to accomplish what you want.

Comment: Are you using input of type `date`? or just a text input?

Comment: The input is a text field with Jquery datepicker. Input format is DD/MM/YYYY. I will try to use a date library like Nicholas proposes

Comment: Solved! Thanks for the help!

Comment: @SenneVandenputte No problem, feel free to upvote the comments that helped